# Cannot work with selenium(Python) with firefox browser (Webdriver Manager) in UBUNTU 23.04

Tags: python, 23.04, selenium

I am trying to run a basic script using selenium (python) in Ubuntu 23.04 (Latest).

As I cannot use Pip in ubuntu 23.04. When I tried with pip to install **selenium and webdriver Manager** then this error displayed:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

Then I tried with virtual Environment. I can install selenium and Webdriver Manager in Venv. But then I face a new problem, I write a basic script for **firefox** (Selenium-python) and Webdriver Manager:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.rokomari.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

then the error is displayed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 201, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options, keep_alive=True)
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/media/zahed/Project_Life/Software_Testing/Selenium/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1
```

Also tried with chromium webdriver:
then the choromium browser just opens but it is not loaded the website. got just blank screen [scripts for chromium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPGa7.png)

Now, Can anyone help me how can actually run selenium scripts in ubuntu 23.04 for chrome and firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$ python -m pip ...` ?